# Livewire no datos ya definida en la clase y en la funcion render

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

buenas tardes (GMT-5)

Estoy utilizando Livewire V2 y laravel V10 y he presentado un error

resumidamente estoy mandando mi consulta a traves de la vista, esta misma carga estos datos en la vista pero no en mi "template", he probado unicamente en el archivo "cart" y en este si me dio la query

mi clase es la siguiente:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Website;

use App\Models\Animals;
use App\Models\AnimalsCategory;
use App\Models\Product;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;
use Livewire\Component;

class ShoppingCart extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.website.payment.cart', [
            "animalsCategory" => AnimalsCategory::all(),
        ])->extends('template');
    }
}
```

mi vista es la siguiente:

```
        <ul class="footer-nav-list">
          <li class="footer-nav-item">
            <h2 class="nav-title">Categorias</h2>
          </li>

          <li class="footer-nav-link">
            @foreach($animalsCategory as $item)
            <a href="{{route('shop.category', [
                'animal' => 'gato',
                'animalCategory' => $item->slug
                ])}}">{{$item->name}}</a>
            @endforeach
          </li>
        </ul>
```

probando el codigo asi como lo mande en este momento me da este error:

**Undefined variable $animalsCategory**

en realidad agradesco cualquier tipo de ayuda sobre este error ^^

Comment: Hola, estás intentando pasarle parámetros a una vista que estás poniéndola como enlace al mismo tiempo, por favor revisa la documentación de laravel. Lo que deberías pasar es: `<a href="{{ route('shop.category', $item) }}">{{ $item->name}}</a>` y debes asegurarte que estás recibiendo a `$item`  en dicha vista